# Hash verification by key

Tags: hash, signature, hash-signature

I want to implement the following algorithm, but don't know what tools to use.

D - data

1. I generate some universal value for D - Y
2. I generate some random key - K, get a hash of D by this key - H
3. I want to be able to have a function - F: F(Y, K, H) = true if H is correct and false otherwise.

The main goal: to prove the validity of hash of data by some key using only some piece of original data.

Usage: Say we have computers: A, B, C. A sends some data to B, then the data is deleted from A. Now, I want to be able to check (from nodes A, C) that B contains the data every 10 minutes, but I can't trust it, so I need some tool to be sure, that B isn't fooling me.

Answer: PDP (Proof of Data Posession)

Comment: Are you asking  HMAC or more?

Comment: @kelalaka I want to be able to prove that data exists on another device, so I want to send it requests with different keys, and receive hashes, then check the hashes by some piece of data (of fixed size) extracted from the original data

Comment: @kelalaka added a usage section

Comment: @kelakala I send requests with random keys, so B has to keep the data to calculate the hash for the given key (am I wrong?)

Comment: yeah, that's the biggest problem, i must be able to verify the pair (key, hash) by some small piece of original data (but it must be impossible to get the hash (by a given key) from this snippet)

Comment: Use HMAC, send the key get the HMAC value to verify that, though you will have limited queries with the number of pairs you had stored. There may be a clever solution that I don't see now.

Comment: @kelakala, moreover, I can't precalculate hashes, because the A node is neither trusted, so I must come up with some small data representation, that could work as a hash verifier.

Comment: Could you completely re-write your question including all details...

Comment: oh, sorry for confusion

Comment: Please [don't cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70852888/1820553), only maintain one copy. [See this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/403350)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the A node is neither trusted"? Do you mean A can lie about what data it claims to have stored with B?

Comment: @knaccc yes. The correct answer for was to use some PDP algorithm (Proof of data posession)

Comment: It'd be interesting if you could explain exactly what PDP method satisfies the criteria in your question. As far as I can see, the simplest method of a random challenge $c$ and a response calculated as $H(c\mathbin\|data)$ would not satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @knaccc I'm sorry I'm not really into cryptography, so I can make mistakes. I found out that there's a very powerful thing - homomorphic hashes and it seems like they can help me to build (or find an existing) algorithm, that would solve my problem.